# Populating data from referenced models in different modules in MEAN.JS

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongoose, meanjs

I am absolutely new to the MEAN stack, and I am using the MEAN.js(ver 0.4.2) generator for my project.

I am using the default users module and created a new module 'Topics' using the module generator. I have a basic role based login system using the users module where users can sign up and see/edit their profiles. In the profile, there is a reference to the topics module's mongoose model called 'Topics'.

topic.server.model.js looks like this(this is the schema for the topics) :

```
//Topic Schema
var TopicSchema = new Schema({
  .......
  user: {
    type: Schema.ObjectId,
    ref: 'User'
  }
});
mongoose.model('Topic', TopicSchema);
```

The content from this model can access the data from the users model. But the i cant get the items to show from the topics model, when i am referencing them from the users module.

My users model has this in the schema :

```
var UserSchema = new Schema({
    ......
    interest: [{
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Topic'
    }],
    skills: [{
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Topic'
    }]
});
mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);
```

I am trying to populate the data from topics using the following middleware :

```
exports.userByID = function (req, res, next, id) {
    if (!mongoose.Types.ObjectId.isValid(id)) {
        return res.status(400).send({
            message: 'User is invalid'
        });
    }
    User.findById(id, '-salt -password').populate('interest', 'name').populate('skills', 'name').exec(function (err, user) {
        if (err) {
            return next(err);
        } else if (!user) {
            return next(new Error('Failed to load user ' + id));
        }

        req.model = user;
        next();
    });
};
```

I would need a little guidance as to how do i get the data in front end to show, something like {{user.interest.name}}.

**Edit**
In the users.profile.server.controller, the json is not getting created from this :

```
exports.me = function (req, res, next) {
    var id = req.user._id;
    User.findOne({
        _id: id
    }).populate('interest', 'name').populate('skills', 'name').exec(function(err, userData) {
        if (err) return next(err);
        if (!userData) return next(new Error('Failed to load User ' + id));
        res.json(userData || null);
        next();
    });
};
```

Getting the following error in the terminal :

```
GET /api/users/me 400 22.173 ms - -
Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.
```

Comment: You're populating "name" but there is no Name Schema? Is the name a property of a topic? Besides that you can populate by using `.populate("interest skills")` and it will populate all the documents.

Comment: Thanks Thomas, well I have already done that, but still it doesnt seem to work. Dont know what I am missing !!

Comment: I have tested it locally and both `interest` and `skills` are returned populated. Are you still stuck on this or is the edit your only problem at the moment?

Comment: Hey Thomas, thanks again, well i just fixed it. Took me a while to understand that i messed up big time in the users.client service file, also the  the admin authorization policies were not able to access the apis i created. Also the users client routes didnt have the proper parameters. Its seems to be working for now. Thanks again man :)